# Prevent Bootstrap navbar from displaying in multiple lines without collapsing into icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a simple Bootstrap Navbar with just couple of items in them. And at width less than 768 it displays in 2 rows. How do I display both the items in a single row as is in higher widths(I don't want to use collapse feature)

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class=""><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***(Updated 2018)***

The `navbar-nav` will always stack items at screen width less than 768 px., but you can override the vertical stacking like this..

```
.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 Demo](http://bootply.com/gdrP1tkY0c)

In **Bootstrap 4**, you just use the navbar-expand class...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Item 2</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/GpHXfotIO2)